# How prove this$\left|\frac{\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\tau)}}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right|\le e^{|\mathrm{Im}\sqrt{\lambda}|\cdot\tau}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

let $\lambda $ is a any complex numbers,and $\tau\in[0,1]$

show that
$$\left|\dfrac{\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\tau)}}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right|\le e^{|\mathrm{Im}\sqrt{\lambda}|\cdot\tau}$$

my idea:
$$\left|\dfrac{\sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\tau)}}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right|\le \int_{0}^{\tau}|\cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot s)}|ds$$

follow I can't solve it,Thank you

Comment: if you take $\sqrt{\lambda}= a+b\mathrm{i}$, then compute $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot s)$ by using $\exp(ix) = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, you will see $|\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot s)|\le \exp(|b|s)$.

Comment: Is$\tau=2\pi$ here?

Comment: I have solve this problem